# How to insert JSON result to database?

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restplus

I'm building a simple REST using Flask-RESTPlus to get all GitHub user data from their specific username.

I have got the result in JSON format.
But now, I want to insert the result to my database.

I have declared my model columns with same name with key on JSON result.
Here is the snippet of my model:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user_v2"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    login = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, index=True)
    node_id = db.Column(db.String)
    avatar_url = db.Column(db.String)
```

and let's says the result from API was like this:

```
{
    "login": "trinanda",
    "id": 25479663,
    "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjI1NDc5NjYz",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/25479663?v=4"
}
```

There are the key on the result was same with my columns name with my models.

I have tried to insert the result with this code, but the things that make me confused are it gives me null value on all of my user columns.

```
class UserResource(Resource):

    def post(self):
        schema = UserSchema()
        github_field = request.json
        username = github_field.get('username')

        github_user_data = get_github_user_data(username)

        user = User(**github_user_data)

        try:
           db.session.add(user)
           db.session.commit()
        except Exception as e:
           return str(e)

        return {
             'status': 'success',
             'user': schema.dump(user).data
        }
```

So.. the point of my questions are, how to insert the JSON result to database..?

**EDIT:**
Here is my `github_user_data`:

```
import requests
github_scraper_url = 'https://api.github.com/users/'
def get_github_user_data(username):
    response = requests.get(github_scraper_url+username)
    return response.json()
```

Comment: Does `github_user_data` is being populated? And does it fit exactly on your User model?

Comment: You should not catch `Exception` directly, instead catch SQLAlchemy base exception

Comment: Here is my github_user_data:

`import requests`
`github_scraper_url = 'https://api.github.com/users/'`
`def get_github_user_data(username):`
    `response = requests.get(github_scraper_url+username)`
    `return response.json()`

Comment: What is the format of github_user_data that you received, please hide the values if they are sensitive data

Comment: I have edited my questions and added my `github_user_data`  @geckos

Comment: Maybe override the model constructor and fill the values manually?

Comment: I think that's not the best practice @CloC

Comment: `flask-sqlalchemy` [documentation](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/) (at the end of the first section) does not advise against that : "_If you decide to override the constructor for any reason, make sure to keep accepting **kwargs and call the super constructor with those **kwargs to preserve this behavior_", so you CAN override the constructor and have better control on what it does, or even inspect what's happening in there for debug purposes.